# Why is $d\bar{d} \rightarrow s\bar{s}$ possible via a gluon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

Following on from [this specific diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/523428/pion-and-proton-make-kaon-and-another-strange-particle-x-why-is-this-the-str), I am not sure why this is possible via a gluon:

> Why is $d\bar{d} \rightarrow s\bar{s}$ possible via a gluon?

The down quarks have a mass lower than the strange quarks, so how does the gluon change the down-antidown pair into a strange-antistrange pair?

This makes me wonder whether I am incorrect in also thinking an electron-postitron annihilating to give a photon which then turns into a muon-antimuon is impossible?

Comment: All mass considerations may be satisfied given sufficient collision energy in the annihilation products. It is crucial the starting quark combination is colored, if you want one gluon. Otherwise, if you start from a cold singlet, you'd need at least two gluons, in a color singlet state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is $d\bar{d} \rightarrow s\bar{s}$ possible via a gluon?

It is an annihilation reaction. Annihilations mean that all the quantum numbers of the particle antiparticle add up to zero, only energy exists. This energy can appear as new elementary particles where again the the quantum numbers add up to zero. As Zachos comments, the color quantum numbers should add up to zero in order for the process with one gluon obeys the zero quantum numbers rule of annihilations.

> The down quarks have a mass lower than the strange quarks, so how does the gluon change the down-antidown pair into a strange-antistrange pair?

All elementary  particle interactions are described with [the four vectors of energy momentum.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) For the reaction to go the two incoming particles' added four momenta have to have a center of mass energy larger than the sum of the masses of the two outgoing particles.

> This makes me wonder whether I am incorrect in also thinking an electron-postitron annihilating to give a photon which then turns into a muon-antimuon is impossible?

Of course you are incorrect, the whole series of e+e- ending with the LEP collider generate a large number of all possible pairs, as long as the quantum numbers add up to zero in input and output , and the beams of e+e- have enough energy.

[image: epbeams]